# Replace text to image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery script for validating the file extension.

```
function ValidateExtension() {
    var allowedFiles = [".csv", ".xlsx", ".txt"];
    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("product_file1");
    var lblError = document.getElementById("lblError");
    var regex = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(" + allowedFiles.join('|') + ")$");
    if (!regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
        lblError.innerHTML = "Please upload files having extensions: <b>" + allowedFiles.join(', ') + "</b> only.";
        return false;
    }
    lblError.innerHTML = "Your file has been imported.Please wait few for minutes";
    return true;
}
```

Here! what I am trying to do, The above code is like this:

```
 lblError.innerHTML = "Your file has been imported.Please wait few for minutes";
```

But I am changing link this,

```
  lblError.innerHTML = '<img src="/assets/spin.gif">';
```

NOTE:Why? I am editing this code means.When i have to uploading a file the message will be display the text but i want display image only,

This is possible?

Comment: Exactly what is your question and whats the problem? Is `<img src="/assets/spin.gif">` being shown as text and you want it to be as HTML?

Comment: Please tell you problem clearly.

Comment: In my script display the text message link "Your file has been imported.Please wait few for minutes", But i want display gif image.I don't no how to insert the image in my script.This my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember you need to use escape characters while you try to insert an image tag in `innerHTML` component. Do it like this and it will 100% work .Try this code below

```
<img src=\`assets/spin.gif\`>
```

Let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible.

Look https://jsfiddle.net/1kzoqg8x/

```
var lblError = document.getElementById("lblError");
lblError.innerHTML = '<img src="http://media.iterar.co/app-site/images/spinner.gif" />';
```

This is it you need?